# Получить список групп, в которые входит пользователь (не ldap)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, auth, active-directory

Добрый день всем. 
Делаю аутентификацию через Active Directory следующим кодом:

```
    Protected Sub Unnamed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim directoryEntry As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://TEST-SERVER/" + Request.Form(5) + ",user")
    Try
        directoryEntry.RefreshCache()
        directoryEntry.Close()
        Dim dirEntry As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://TEST-SERVER", "TEST-SERVER\" + Request.Form(5), Request.Form(6))
        Try
            dirEntry.RefreshCache()
            dirEntry.Close()
            Session("UserLogin") = Request.Form(5)
        Catch
            showAlertScript()
            ' Response.Write("NO PASS")
        End Try
    Catch
        showAlertScript()
        '  Response.Write("NO USER")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Вопрос: как я могу узнать список групп AD, в которые входит пользователь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий код выведет имя пользователя и все группы, в которых он состоит.

```
    Dim dirr As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://TEST-SERVER")
    Dim User As DirectoryEntry = dirr.Children.Find(userName, "User")
    Dim obGroups As Object = User.Invoke("Groups")
    Response.Write(userName + ":")
    For Each obG In obGroups
        Dim obGpEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(obG)
        Response.Write(obGpEntry.Name & "; ")
    Next
```